# Replace -inf with zero value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, infinity

I have an array:

```
x =  numpy.array([-inf, -inf, 37.49668579])
```

Is there a way to change the -inf values to just 0?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

There is:

```
from numpy import inf
x[x == -inf] = 0
```

Comment: this is around 20% faster than np.isneginf based on my test

Comment: How are the brackets used here?  Is this indexing with a conditional, or list comprehension?

Comment: No list comprehension. It is numpy indexing using a boolean array. In this case: "Elements of x equal to -inf".

Comment: NameError: global name 'inf' is not defined

Comment: @johnktejik did you run the import statement `from numpy import inf` ?

Comment: I believe it's better to use `X[~np.isfinite(X)]` = 0 or `x[numpy.isneginf(x)] = 0` as in the second answer

Answer (score 26):

Perhaps even easier and more flexible to use `numpy.nan_to_num`:

```
numpy.nan_to_num(x, neginf=0) 

Out[1]: array([ 0.        ,  0.        , 37.49668579])
```

Answer (score 25):

Use `isneginf` http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isneginf.html#numpy.isneginf

```
x[numpy.isneginf(x)] = 0
```